# Gitlab set up mailjet in gitlab.rb

Tags: smtp, config, gitlab, mailjet

I'm trying since a few hours to set up a mail server in Gitlab(omnibus) using mailjet.

In the mailjet smtp settings I've got some credentials:

-Username(API Key)

-Password(Secret Key)

-SMTP Server ....mailjet.com

-Port: 25 or 587 (some providers block port 25)

-Use TLS : optional

The Configs in gitlab.rb look like this:

```
################################
# GitLab email server settings #
################################

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "....mailjet.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "(Username(API Key))"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "(Password(Secret Key))"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "my websites domain"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
```

This doesn't work.

Is it correct to use the websites domain as 'smtp_domain' or should I use ...mailjet.com?

Does somebody knows how to set this up?

[Here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md) are some examples  how to do the setup but no informations about mailjet.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from mailjet support and it works now.

Use port 80 and disable tls and ssl.

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "....mailjet.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 80
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "(Username(API Key))"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "(Password(Secret Key))"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "....mailjet.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
```